Cant see array values inside struct when I returned
    /******************** STRUCT ********************/
    struct TwentyOneContest {
        address creator;
        uint256 rank;
        uint256 enterPrice;
        uint256 collectedPrice;
        address contestant1Address;
        address contestant2Address;
        uint256[] contestant1DrawedNumbers;
        uint256[] contestant2DrawedNumbers;
        bool isContestant1Turn;
        bool isContestant2Turn;
        bool isContestant1Finished;
        bool isContestant2Finished;
        bool end;
    }
    TwentyOneContest[] public twentyOneContests;
    function createContest(uint256 _enterPrice) public payable {
        /*************** RANK CREATION ***************/
        uint256 contestRank = uint256(
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    tx.origin,
                    blockhash(block.number - 1),
                    block.timestamp
                )
            )
        );
        /*************** REVERT ***************/
        require(
            msg.value == Based.CONTEST_CREATION_PRICE,
            "Invalid contest creation price"
        );
        /*************** STRUCT ****************/
        uint256[] memory _contestant1DrawedNumbers;
        uint256[] memory _contestant2DrawedNumbers;
        twentyOneContests.push(
            TwentyOneContest(
                msg.sender,
                contestRank,
                _enterPrice,
                0,
                address(0),
                address(0),
                _contestant1DrawedNumbers,
                _contestant2DrawedNumbers,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false
            )
        );
        /*************** MAPPING ***************/
        isContestExist[contestRank] = true;
        getContestIndexFromContestRank[contestRank] = increasingNumber;
        increasingNumber++;
        /*************** EVENT ***************/
        emit ContestCreated(contestRank);
        /*************** TRANSFER ***************/
        payable(Based.CONTRACT_OWNER).transfer(msg.value);
    }

cant see the drawedNumbers for both contestant with web3js. When I return twentyOneContests[0] I can see other elements but no drawedNumbers thinking might be memory causing this.

I stopped using array inside struct and found another way of doing it

Where are you assigning the _contestant1DrawedNumbers and _contestant2DrawedNumbers?

Can you share the minimum reproducible code ?

@SYEDASADKAZMI there is twentyOneContests.push(TwemtyOneContest) there where I'm assigning

more code coming right up

Yes, but these are basically empty arrays. uint256[] memory _contestant1DrawedNumbers;         uint256[] memory _contestant2DrawedNumbers;. You’ve to assign them with some drawed numbers as per your code logic.

fixed the problem thx
